# limits with functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hello I hope somebody can help me.
I have question re limits. Suppose $r$ is a function and 
$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{r(x)}{x}=1$

How do I show that  $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}⁡ \dfrac{r^2(x)}{x}  +\dfrac{2r^2(x)}{x}  + r(x)=1$

I don’t know where to start? Do I divide the highest term in the denominator ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't write $\frac{3r^2(x)}{x}$ instead?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: the first term in the second equation should be r2(x)/x^2 not over x

Answer (score 2):

Since $r(x) = \dfrac{r(x)}{x} \cdot x$ the product limit law tells you that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} r(x) = 1 \cdot 0 = 0$. This leads to 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}⁡ \dfrac{r^2(x)}{x}  +\dfrac{2r^2(x)}{x}  + r(x)= 
\lim_{x\to 0}⁡\left( r(x) \cdot \dfrac{r(x)}{x}  + r(x) \cdot \dfrac{2r(x)}{x} + r(x)\right) = 0$$